# General serialization library/framework for C++

Tags: library, software-development, c++

Suppose you want to be able to serialize and de-serialize and bunch of types and classes. If they're close enough together semantically, you might be able to use some domain-specific facility like structured markup documents, graphs, etc. But for the general case - what are our options?

The C++ standard library does not provide generic serialization facilities. Boost has [Boost.Serialization](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html), which may still be relevant, but is, after all, almost 20 years old, and its "TODO" list was [last revised in 2008](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_71_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html).

Required features:

- Actively maintained
- Is C++11-cognizant  (to the extent C++1 features are relevant to serialization)
- Gratis
- Libre
- Multi-platform

Desired features:

- Is cognizant of C++14, 17 and 20 features

Answer (score 1):

For C++11 I can recommend **cereal**. To some extent it even works as a drop-in replacement for Boost.Serialization with only minimal code changes. In my experience the documentation is pretty good and it is header-only. https://uscilab.github.io/cereal/

Comment: 1. If it's C++11, why are changes only minimal? I'd expect some API differences. 2. So, is the idea to have the same functionality as `Boost::Serial` but without Boost? Or are there aspects which are markedly better than its inspiration?

Answer (score 1):

For C++17 there is the library **Cista**, which borrows inspiration from Protobuf but without having to compile protocol buffers in an intermediate step. It features things like zero-copy and uses C++17 structured bindings to implement rudimentary reflection. This unfortunately requires significant code changes because you have to replace STL containers with Cista equivalents to make use of zero-copy. https://cista.rocks/

Comment: 1. "zero-copy" - in what context? 2. What is its benefit relative to cereal, if here you have to replace your containers? Does it offer better speed? Compilation time? Other metrics?

Comment: @einpoklum If I understand it correctly, allocations are performed on memory-mapped files, which means that serialization and deserialization boils down to copying a pointer. The benefit over cereal is mainly speed. I haven't used Cista extensively myself, so I can't make any statement about other metrics, but there are some benchmarks on their website.